# Ruby on Rails PostgreSQL error on Heroku

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I am using SQLite with development and PostgreSQL for production on Heroku with the geocoder gem. it requires me to have a lat and lon attributes which work perfect in development (SQLite) but throw me an error on production in heroku when I run the logs after the create action is run. The following is the error on heroku log:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric - character varying
LINE 1: ...3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((53.8103 - location...
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I have tried changing the lat, lon attributes to int and deployed again but that does not work either. (bearing in mind everything still works in development)

Comment: If you are deploying to Postgres it makes a whole lot of sense to develop/test on Postgres so that you catch bugs like this. In this case I'm guessing that your latitude and longitude column type is not float but rather something like  varchar or text. SQLite does not care and will happily cast for you, Postgres not so much. https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/69

Comment: The solution given in this link suggest that I should change to float. However, that does not register with PostgreSQL language the migration is not complete and a USING clause is suggested. That contains Postgres Syntax. Where do I use that in production mode?

Comment: I'm sorry I have no idea what you are saying. If you want to change the type of the column to fix it you would create a migration which changes the column type, commit it to heroku and then run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Im saying thats what I did, but I got another error which i looked upon and the solution for that error was to use something called a USING clause. The syntax of it was somewhat like:`ALTER TABLE listings ALTER longitude TYPE integer USING longitude::int;` Now I cant use that in the migration file now cant I. So my question was where do you use this like of code to fix the issue? If the answer is what I think it is then Maybe if i need to transfer to PG in development like you suggested...

Comment: Using the same DB in test/dev is a good idea, but it wont magically fix this issue. You can use custom SQL in a migration by using `execute`. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-reversible

Comment: ok, but if i'm running rake db:migrate using `execute` which is only postgres syntax, it wont migrate locally how do I fix that?

Comment: Change to postgres locally.

Comment: Will the same principle apply to the ip address column as it is set to string in local database?

Comment: The question does not make sense. You would usually use a string column to store IP adresses - you can't use a float since its not a number. Its a sequence of numbers.